# WSO2 ESB processing a large file, stopping and restarting?

Tags: loops, wso2, mediator, smooks, wso2-esb

Is it possible in the WSO2 ESB to process a large file (with each line representing a single record/message), and stop or pause the processing within the file, then restart where it left off? (using the Smooks mediator and/or Iterate mediator, so any other mechanism)

It appears that if you are processing a large file (say with 10K entries) you cannot stop or pause the processing (or say the ESB is brought down in the middle of processing the file), and then restart where it was stopped. Upon restarting either the whole file has to be reprocessed, or the file is dumped to the error folder and skipped. Is this correct?

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this cannot be done in a straight forward manner. However you could probably split the large file in to smaller files using Smooks mediator (message splitting) [1], and use VFS processing on it [2]. Each file on the VFS location that is processed will either be deleted or moved, so whenever the process restarts it will not process the already processed messages/files.

[1] - https://github.com/smooks/smooks/tree/v1.5.1/smooks-examples/file-router/

[2] - https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=33136056

Comment: Thanks. We actually use this pattern also, but if the proxy using the Smooks mediator [1] is stopped in the middle of splitting the file, when it is restarted won't it attempt to re-split the file and make a new set of smaller files, which in turn would be re-processed by the second proxy [2]?

Comment: Yes, that's something which slipped my mind. I can't think of anything else ATM unfortunately, but you would have better luck by directing this question to WSO2 dev mailing list - dev@wso2.org, http://wso2.com/mail/

Comment: Thanks. I'll post it to the mailing list.